# Generate key pair and entropy

Tags: java, key-generation

I would like to use the method described in https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwk-generation to generate a key pair in a java application:

```
import java.util.*;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.*;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.gen.*;

// Generate 2048-bit RSA key pair in JWK format, attach some metadata
RSAKey jwk = new RSAKeyGenerator(2048)
    .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE) // indicate the intended use of the key
    .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) // give the key a unique ID
    .generate();

// Output the private and public RSA JWK parameters
System.out.println(jwk);

// Output the public RSA JWK parameters only
System.out.println(jwk.toPublicJWK());
```

This code will be executed when the application starts.
The application will start in AWS (using kubernetes).

Is it possible that the generation will fail because there won't be enough entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea of "entropy running out" is quite a prevailing one, especially among novice cryptographers. Let me be very clear here: Once the internal state is sufficiently random, you can basically generate as much randomness as you want. [<sup>[Source]</sup>](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62748/543)

So when is something *sufficiently random*? That depends on the environment. A busy machine, like a desktop computer or an AWS server, will have countless entropy sources, so even milliseconds after boot, your CSPRNG will have an internal state, which an attacker will not be able to predict.

> Is it possible that the generation will fail because there won't be enough entropy?

It is possible, depending on how the library is written. It is most likely OS-dependent, meaning that there is a chance that on Linux, it will read from `/dev/random`. Now, I won't go into details, because whether or not the mechanism of "available entropy" is a good idea or not has been discussed extensively, but the gist of it is that `/dev/random` blocks reads if it believes there isn't enough entropy available. Note that it will *block*, not *fail* - meaning that the task could hang for a second, or a minute, white it attempts to read from the entropy source. On the other hand, if reading from `/dev/urandom`, it will not block and the key will generate as usual.

---

By the way, unless you have a *really* good reason to use RSA, I would recommend against using that and using X25519 instead. Performance is *much* better and key generation requires less entropy while retaining the same level of security.

Comment: I am not actually worried about entropy running out. I need to generate only one certificate. I am just worried that when the server starts up in kubernetes there won't be enough entropy yet. I have seen people experiencing this in other posts and so I am wondering if it can happen with my application as well.

Comment: I am using RSA because the library nimbusds does not seem to support the export to key pair when the algorithm is not RSA.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri As the documentation says, that's because it requires the optional [Tink](https://github.com/google/tink) dependency. Regarding you application start: The most likely behavior is that it will not block and generate just fine, or block for a very short time. Which begs the question: Why do you generate new keys on startup?

Comment: I am generating the keys because I cannot store them in the database or in the file system unless I encrypt them (and that means to call an external service, etc... it becomes very soon a lot more complicated.)

Comment: @MarcoAltieri That seems like an issue with the application design, as asymmetric keys are generally not designed to be "thrown away" like this

Comment: I am not sure that I understand why that is a design issue. I need these keys to sign JWTs. The JWts are used for client authentication in a OAuth2 flow. These JWTs are very short lived and so there is no reason why it shouldn't be safe to use a different key after a startup if it's true what you said about the entropy.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri I see. In this case, that's fine and reasonable.